# prevent to duplicate entry in sqllite database android

Tags: php, android, database, sqlite

I created two tables :

1. Item.db
2. TempItem.db

Both tables has two entries when I added third entry in Item.db table and copy this entry into TempItem.db this time duplicate entry added in my TempItem table.

How to prevent this ?

My source code

```
// Item.db table array
for(int ip=0; ip<results.size(); ip++)
{
// TempItem.db table array
    for(int ig=0; ig<resultmain.size(); ig++)
    {
        // Check Both database item
        if((results.get(ip).item).equals(resultmain.get(ig).item))
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "no", 100).show();
        }
        else
        {
            mb.insertEntry(1, 1, 1, 1, "Baby", "1", "100", "100");
        }                        
    }
}
```

But every time duplicate value is getting added.

Comment: visit https://www.buzzingandroid.com/2013/01/sqlite-insert-or-replace-through-contentprovider/

Answer (score 1):

you can use [insertWithOnConflict](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)

```
db.insertWithOnConflict(tableName, null, contentValues,SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
```

Comment: Thank you for your great suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is by declaring the id of the table as primary key or attribute it with unique constraint. Now sqlite would throw an exception unique constraint when you try to enter duplicate record.

Comment: Thank you for your great suggestions.

Comment: If you think it is correct, pls accept it as answer.